# How do I stop Google Chrome windows from "following" me across Unity workspaces?

Tags: 18.04, unity, google-chrome, workspaces

I've got Google Chrome in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS running Unity, and when I switch workspaces, the Chrome windows follow me to the new one, regardless of what window I have focused at the time (and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>, so I'm sure I'm not just bringing them along by accident). How can I disable/correct this behaviour?

Comment: I am not on 18.04 and / or Unity, but did you try to disable "Always on Visible Workspace"? Right click on Chrome title bar and see if this option is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the default behaviour was that the workspace would only include the primary display (and I always put Chrome on the secondaries). Using `gnome-tweaks`, under "Workspaces", by switching "Display handling" to "Workspaces span displays", I made it work the way it was intended.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, switching virtual desktops is accomplished by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+[any direction]. You might be using the keyboard shortcut to move the currently highlighted window to another virtual desktop instead.